# A C++ alternative to Matlab's fmincon optimisation? Need a quicker easy alternative

Tags: c++, performance, matlab, optimization, matrix

I need to use optimisation to solve for the variables in the following matrix:

[figure 1.0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J2ZGg.png)

The yellow highlighted matrix contains all the variables I want to solve for.

Before for each case, the equations of motion were solved for each time point using an optimization approach that is based upon a cost function adapted from the work of Crowninshield & Brand [24] and Raikova
[25]. The optimization was solved using the optimization toolbox of MATLAB
(R2103a; The Mathworks, Inc, 2013):

Here is he cost function.

[Figure 2.0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yLNrQ.png)

I realise all these matrices and equations will have variables you won't necessarily understand. However, my question is this- Is there an open source alternative for optimisation with similar functionality as fmincon? I am working on finding a faster alternative so speed is my priority.

This is for a student project. If I show my professor some tangible results in having been able to reduce the time taken for solving he will be quite happy. As far as I can understand he says the fmincon function on matlab is slow and inefficient.

Thanks!

Comment: Should be marked as duplicate. Check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6403282/non-linear-least-squares-optimization-library-for-c. Or this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5439321/implementation-of-matlabs-fmincon-function-in-c?rq=1.

Comment: May be you can elaborate why you consider  fmincon to be slow (compared to what?). fmincon has quite a few knobs you can tune (e.g. algorithm). Furthermore make sure you pass on analytic gradients instead of letting the algorithm do finite differences.